# Django POST to Facebook API Returns GraphMethodException

Tags: python, django, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to publish to my Facebook wall from my site. I have logged in to my site with Facebook and have also granted `publish_actions` permission but when I try to publish to Facebook I get error.

Facebook says I can publish to user's wall by making an HTTP POST request as below:

```
POST graph.facebook.com
  /{user-id}/feed?
    message={message}&
    access_token={access-token}
```

`user-id`, `message` and `access-token`[token is long-lived] are fine and correct as returned by Facebook API call response.

I have also `pip install requests`, [an elegant and simple HTTP library for Python, built for human beings](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

**My code:**

```
import requests
if user.publish:         
    message = post_message.encode('utf8')
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/feed".format(user.facebook_id)
    msg = {'message':message, 'access_token':user.access_token }
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(msg))
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

The code returns the error below:

**{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}**

Comment: which api version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making request to a wrong url, it should be

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"
```

Also facebook doesn't allow apps to publish posts on friends wall. You can only publish posts to your wall only.